# What does this mean? - if (null === ($bar = $foo->getBar()))

Tags: php

When we have something like:

```
if (null === ($bar = $foo->getBar())) {

}
```

Are we doing three things on this single line ?
Are we:

1) Declaring a variable.

2) Attribute that variable a value.

3) Check if that variable value is null.

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, exactly like:

```
$bar = $foo->getBar();
if (null === $bar) {

}
```

`$bar` will receive the value returned by `$foo->getBar()`, and then the expression tests whether that (the result of the assignment expression, which is the value that got assigned to `$bar`) is `=== null`. (And if this is the first use of `$bar`, then it's creating a new variable.)

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot. I like that important precision. Only if $bar isn't created before, it will create it.

Answer (score 2):

First you execute function getBar() which returns something what is assigned to variable $bar. Then operator === returns true if $bar is equal to null and they are the same type (null type).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Answer (score 1):

it's equal to:

```
 $bar = $foo->getBar();
 if ($bar === null) {

 }
```

Keep in mind that there is difference between === and ==. === is exact comparison operator, so 0 ==null is true but 0 === null is false. "" == null is true, "" === null is false.

Comment: Thanks for that null add on. :)